# How to parse the following dict in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a following dict structure passed to my Django template, whose keys or length are unknown to me:

```
config_values = {
    'Kafka': {
        'KAFKA_BROKER_URL': 'localhost:9092',
    },
    'Redis': {
        'REDIS_HOST': 'localhost',
        'REDIS_PORT': '6379',
    },
}
```

I want to show it in my templates as shown below

- Kafka

  - KAFKA_BROKER_URL = localhost:9092
- Redis

  - REDIS_HOST = localhost
  - REDIS_PORT = 6379

I'm relatively new to python and dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through a dict in a django template just the way you do in python.

Look at this.

```
{% for i,j in config_file.items %}
 {{i}} // i will give you 'kafka'
  {% for k,l in j.items %}
   {{k}} {{l}} // k will give you 'kafka_broker_url' and l will give you localhost:9092
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```